# window.showModalDialog dialogWidth property not working in IE

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a 2.0 framework ASP.Net page that runs in our controled environment (IE 7).
The `dialogWidth` property seems not to be working. The scrip is as follows:

```
var win = window.showModalDialog ('Page.aspx', 'PopupPage', 'dialogHeight:600px,dialogWidth:800px,resizable:0');
```

The `dialogHeight` works fine but no matter what I change the `dialogWidth` to - it seems to be limited to a width of about 250px. In the configuration above the modal popup is higher that it is wide - even though width is 800 and height is 600.

Comment: ??? unadorned has nothing to do with the question you asked. The problem was with the comma delimited arguments. It ignored all other arguments after dialogHeight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var returnValue = window.showModalDialog(sUrl,'','unadorned:yes;resizable:1;
dialogHeight:550px;dialogwidth:985px;scroll:no;status=no');
```

Someone I work with had the same problem, and this fixed his problem...

Comment: unadorned:yes appears to have been the key - worked like a champ!! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The options must be delimited by semicolons, not commas.

```
var win = window.showModalDialog ('Page.aspx', 'PopupPage', 'dialogHeight:600px; dialogWidth:800px; resizable:0');
```